# How to change ng-model?

Tags: angularjs

There is Angular JS:

```
$scope.changeSelect = function (item){
    if(item == 0){
      // Здесь изменить ng-model элемента
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-change="changeSelect(city)">
<select ng-model="country" ng-change="changeSelect(country)">
```

I need reset `ng-model` for each `ng-change` if condition is true

#### What I want

When I call function `ng-change="changeSelect()"` I need check value on zero, if true, change this ng-model value to null. Updated question

Comment: Can you create a plunkr, your question is not clear

Comment: Simply, when I call function `ng-change="changeSelect()"` I need check value on zero, if true, change this `ng-model` value to null. Updated question

Comment: Hi. Have you seen my answer? Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

### Html :

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-change="changeSelect(this.city)">
<select ng-model="country" ng-change="changeSelect(this.country)">
```

### JS Cde

```
$scope.changeSelect = function (item){
    if (item == 0) {
         item=null;
    }
}
```

### Update :

Another way is manually thinking Way :p

```
 <select ng-model="city" ng-change="changeSelect(this.city,'city')">
    <select ng-model="country" ng-change="changeSelect(this.country,'country')">
```

.........

```
$scope.changeSelect = function (item, selectedContex) {
            if (item == 0) {
                if (selectedContex == "city") {
                    $scope.city = null;
                    return false;
                }
                else if (selectedContex = 'country') {
                    $scope.country = null;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tried, doesn't work, but you are near right solution

Comment: Tried too: `ng-model="formData.city" ng-change="changeSelect(this.formData.city)"`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<select  ng-model="(changeSelect(city) ? null: city)">
```

Script:

```
$scope.changeSelect = function (item){
    if(item == 0){
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you need?.

Comment: I tried: `ng-model="(changeSelect($scope.formData.city) ? null: formData.city)">` does not work for me

Comment: Try this: `ng-model="(changeSelect({{formData.city}}) ? null: formData.city)">`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [angular-reset-on](https://github.com/waldirpereira/angular-reset-on) directive I've wrote. With this directive you can specify a condition to reset each field.

For example:

```
<select ng-model="city" ng-reset-on="city == 0">
<select ng-model="country" ng-reset-on="country == 0">
```

It's as simple as that. :)